# Using table() to count occurrences of strings in the R results in some, but not all, incorrect outputs

Tags: mysql, r

I usually find all my answers by searching here, and I've never had to post anything before. However this is a very particular problem and I haven't been able to find an answer. I hope you can help.

I have this table, called "FSR":

```
Mouse Day Percent.Rewarded Percent.Premature
Y3.5   1             0.72              0.73
Y3.6   1             0.47              0.68
Y3.7   1             0.74              0.71
X7.1   1             0.74              0.79
X7.2   1             0.74              0.80
AA1.1   1             0.91              0.84
AA1.2   1             0.70              0.75
AA1.3   1             0.95              0.85
```

I want to count the number of times each Mouse ID appears in the column Mouse, which should be easy:

```
FSRCounts <- table(FSR$Mouse)
```

So far, so good. This appears to work:

```
print(FSRCounts)

AA1.1 AA1.2 AA1.3  X7.1  X7.2  Y3.5  Y3.6  Y3.7 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

If I want to know how many times a particular mouse has appeared, this also works, no matter which mouse:

```
FSRCounts["Y3.6"]
Y3.6 
   1 

FSRCounts["AA1.1"]
AA1.1 
    1
```

However, for some reason when I use another table, called data, to get the mouse IDs the code doesn't work for every mouse and I can't figure out why.

Here's the table "data". I have deleted columns irrelevant to this question:

```
                           Experiment mouse
1          RIGHT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  X6.1
2           LEFT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  X6.2
3          RIGHT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  Y3.1
4           LEFT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  Y3.2
5          RIGHT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  Y3.3
6           LEFT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  Y3.4
7  RIGHT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR  Y3.5
8   LEFT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR  Y3.6
9  RIGHT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR  Y3.7
10  LEFT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR  X7.1
11 RIGHT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR  X7.2
12  LEFT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR AA1.1
13 RIGHT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR AA1.2
14  LEFT_5sec_reactiontime_gonogo_LMR AA1.3
15         RIGHT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR AA1.4
16          LEFT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR AA1.5
17         RIGHT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR AA1.6
18         RIGHT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  Y4.2
19          LEFT_autoshape_gonogo_LMR  Y4.3
```

And here's the code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
if (grepl("5sec", data[i,"Experiment"])) {
        FiveToday <- T
        FM <- data[i,"mouse"]
        FD <- FSRCounts[FM] + 1
        if (is.na(FSRCounts[FM])){
            FD <- 1
        }
}
}
```

It works for some mice, but not others. I've added the "print()" lines to show exactly where the code is screwing up.

For example, it works for AA1.2:

```
> FM <- data[13,"mouse"]
>       print("FM:")
[1] "FM:"
>       print(FM)
[1] AA1.2
Levels: AA1.1 AA1.2 AA1.3 AA1.4 AA1.5 AA1.6 X6.1 X6.2 X7.1 X7.2 Y3.1 Y3.2 Y3.3 Y3.4 Y3.5 Y3.6 Y3.7 Y4.2 Y4.3
>       print("FSR Count Table:")
[1] "FSR Count Table:"
>       print(FSRCounts)

AA1.1 AA1.2 AA1.3  X7.1  X7.2  Y3.5  Y3.6  Y3.7 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
>       print("Count:")
[1] "Count:"
>       print(FSRCounts[FM])
AA1.2 
    1 
>       FD <- FSRCounts[FM] + 1
>       print("FD:")
[1] "FD:"
>       print(FD)
AA1.2 
    2 
>       if (is.na(FSRCounts[FM])){print("FD is 1") 
+           FD <- 1
}
```

But not for Y3.6:

```
> FM <- data[8,"mouse"]
>       print("FM:")
[1] "FM:"
>       print(FM)
[1] Y3.6
Levels: AA1.1 AA1.2 AA1.3 AA1.4 AA1.5 AA1.6 X6.1 X6.2 X7.1 X7.2 Y3.1 Y3.2 Y3.3 Y3.4 Y3.5 Y3.6 Y3.7 Y4.2 Y4.3
>       print("FSR Count Table:")
[1] "FSR Count Table:"
>       print(FSRCounts)

AA1.1 AA1.2 AA1.3  X7.1  X7.2  Y3.5  Y3.6  Y3.7 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
>       print("Count:")
[1] "Count:"
>       print(FSRCounts[FM])
<NA> 
  NA 
>       FD <- FSRCounts[FM] + 1
>       print("FD:")
[1] "FD:"
>       print(FD)
<NA> 
  NA 
>       if (is.na(FSRCounts[FM])){print("FD is 1") 
+           FD <- 1
+       }
[1] "FD is 1"
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening and fix it? Or suggest an alternate way to do the same thing? Thanks for your help!

Dan Hoops

Comment: It's suspicious that your `data` table is right-aligned. Could there be leading blanks before the values? For example, try `" Y3.6"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I add the mouse IDs to the `data` table elsewhere in my script: 
`rawdatafiles <- list.files() 
for (j in rawdatafiles){
data <- read.csv(j, header = T)
mouse <- c("X6.1", "X6.2", "Y3.1", "Y3.2", "Y3.3", "Y3.4", "Y3.5", "Y3.6", "Y3.7", "X7.1", "X7.2", "AA1.1", "AA1.2", "AA1.3", "AA1.4", "AA1.5", "AA1.6", "Y4.2", "Y4.3")
data <- cbind(data, mouse)
}`

Can this explain why it's right-aligned? And why is that suspicious? Using `class()`, I know that the mouse IDs are of class factor in both the `data` and `FSR` tables.

Comment: So I I still don't know why this happens, but I've got a work-around. Convert all the mouse IDs to characters using `data["mouse"] <- lapply(data["mouse"], as.character)` and suddenly everything works perfectly. Go figure!